# CodeMagic Error, can't publish to google store

Tags: google-play, codemagic

It's my first time linking with codemagic, and I'm trying to link my GitHub to the store, then I have received this error,

`Publishing failed :| Google Play failed to upload artefacts. The caller does not have permission: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The caller does not have permission", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the permission for the service account to access your application is not properly set up.

I would pay very close attention starting from the 8th point in this tutorial:
https://docs.codemagic.io/knowledge-base/google-play-api/

However, I also think that sometimes Google takes some time to get it going, in any case, I would retry creating the service account and paying very close attention to all the details - make sure the service account has access to the right application (also check your bundle id in your local settings etc).

Comment: The link is expired

Comment: https://docs.codemagic.io/yaml-publishing/google-play/

Answer (score 2):

Based on the CodeMagic documentation:

https://docs.codemagic.io/flutter-publishing/publishing-to-google-play/

It seems that the first time required to upload the AAB manually to the Google Play Store.

> The very first version of the app must be added to Google Play
> manually. You can download the app_release.aab from the build
> artifacts. In addition, each uploaded binary must have a different
> version; see how to automatically increment build version on
> Codemagic.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I've forgotten to invite service account as user in Google Play Console.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I hadn't properly 'invited' the service account into my google play console (Google Play Console -> Setup -> Users and Permissions) my users list now shows my personal user + the google cloud service account user.